# How to evaluate a squared sum?

Tags: soft-question, summation

I need (the name of) the formula to evaluate $(x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n ) ^2$ . I know the question is not very interesting, but I am stuck and WolframAlpha also doesn't get my input.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) ?

Answer (score 2):

$$\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\bigg)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n x_ix_j= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 + 2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j= i+1}^nx_ix_j$$

Unfortunately it doesn't get much better than this without knowledge of a pattern or symmetry in $\{x_i\}.$

Comment: shouldn't it be $$\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\bigg)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 + 2\sum_{\color{red}{i=1}}^n\sum_{j= i+1}^nx_ix_j$$

Comment: Sorry, got confused there for a moment. Just made an edit. There also needs to be $(n-1)$ as the upper limit for outer summation